# Getting image data continuously from camera, SurfaceView or SurfaceHolder

Tags: java, android, camera, surfaceview, surfaceholder

So I have this camera preview set up with `Camera`, `SurfaceView` and `SurfaceHolder`.
I have also an `ImageView` where I will be putting a modified version of the camera image and I want this to update lets say once every second.

All code is ready and already working when I load images from "res" but I have a really hard time reading the image data from the camera.

I've tried following already:

1. Creating an `intent` for `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` and starting an `onActivityResult` getting a small thumbnail (enough for me actually) from `(Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data")` 
   *The problem is that this opens the camera App and you need to "manually" take a picture*.
2. Creating a `Camera.PreviewCallback`, taking the `YuvImage`, and converting it to an image using `YuvImage.compressToJpeg(...)`.

   *The problem here is that I can't get it to start no matter when or where i put the* `Camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(PreviewCallback)`.
3. Try to take the data directly from `PreviewHolder` by locking in to the canvas using `lockCanvas()` and trying to convert it to a bitmap
   *Obviously Doesn't work.*

**Edit:**
What is the best way to make this work? I mean QR-Code readers must read the image data out of the camera continuously, how do they work?

Comment: Check out how ZXing does it. https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk%2Fandroid%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fzxing%2Fclient%2Fandroid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I went for option number 2 and finally made it work.

used this callback, forgot the `@Override` before

```
private Camera.PreviewCallback  previewCallback= new Camera.PreviewCallback()
{   
    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data,Camera cam)
    {
            Camera.Size previewSize = cam.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
            YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21,previewSize.width,previewSize.height, null);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0,0,previewSize.width,previewSize.height),80,baos);
            byte[] jdata = baos.toByteArray();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jdata,0,jdata.length);    
    }
};
```

And initiating it using `setPreviewCallback` rather than `setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer`

```
SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceCallback=new SurfaceHolder.Callback() 
{   
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        camera.setPreviewCallback(previewCallback);
    }
}
```

Comment: This might have a bug in it; it assumes the image format is `NV21`. It might be more robust to read the image format out of `cam.getParameters().getPreviewFormat()`.

Comment: Actually, never mind. According to `YuvImage`'s javadoc, it only supports NV21 and YUV2, whereas the camera is only guaranteed across all devices to support NV21, which is the default anyway, and YV12. So NV21 is the only reliable option.